# Yii and Bootstrap pagination access

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, pagination

I don't know how to make pagination with my code. I would put three items per page, but I have no idea how to do it. If anyone can guide me!

```
<?php
$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('username,hash')
->from('cruge_user')
->queryAll();

  echo "<table class='table table-striped' id='connect_table' border=1 style='width:300px'>
            <tr>
              <td>USUARI</td>
              <td>ESTAT</td> 
            </tr><tr>";
  foreach ($rows as $key => $valor) {
  foreach ($valor as $col => $valors) {
    if($col=='username'){
    $username=$valors;
    if($username!=$user){
    echo "<td><i class='icon-user'>__".$valors."</td>";
    }
    }
    //  $( document ).ready(function() {
    if($col=='hash'){
      if($valors!=""){
      if($username!=$user){
      //echo "<td><button id='connect' value='\"$valors\"' type='button'>PLAY</button></td>";
      echo "<td class='success'><button title='clica per jugar' class='btn' id='connect' onclick='envia_hash(\"$valors\")' type='button'></button></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    }else {
        echo "<td><img title='desconectat' src='../img/disable.png'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use cgridview. it makes pagination automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution for you problem is the CGridView widget. It has filter, pagination and your code will be much cleaner.

Take a look [here](http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=UiModule/dataview/gridView)

edit: you can use the bootstrap classes or you can use the [yiibooster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView) widget which is based on bootstrap